# Dojo form/Button change Color

Tags: javascript, dojo

is there a way ti change programmatically the color of the dojo/form/Button?
I always override it in the css, but then the whole style of the button was lost.

Answer (score 1):

Use dom-style's set method.
http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/dom-style.html

ex:

`style.set("button", "color", "red")`

for div with id "button"